# Java Attach API

Tags: java, jvm

I am struggling to understand the purpose of the Attach API (`com.sun.tools.attach.*`). What are its typical uses? Is it to "mock" a JVM so you can test out your code without deploying/launching it, is it a debugger, or does it give you access to the JVM that *will* run your app once its built and ran?

I think I'm getting hung up on the word **attached**. I can't tell if this means "deployed to", "embedded inside of" or other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its for management agents, debuggers etc... to attach to the JVM.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/package-summary.html

e.g. Connect (attach) to a JVM to manage it or interact with it through the debugger.

Its a com.sun API so its not an official Java API. If you ran another vendor's JVM it may not have this api at all.